# Application of this formula: $\int f(u(x)) * u'(x)dx = \int f(u)du $

Tags: integration

according to my book, the following is true:

$\int f(u(x)) * u'(x)dx = \int f(u)du = F(u) + C   $

where u = u(x)

I have the following problem: $\int2xe^{x^2+1}$

here's my attempt at applying the formula above to the problem.

$f(u(x)) = 2xe^{x^2+1}$

$u(x) = x^2 + 1$

so applying the formula gives $\int f(u(x)) * u'(x)dx = 2xe^{x^2+1} * 2x   $

This gets me nowhere, i know the answer is supposed to be $ e^{x^{2} + 1} + C $. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Notice that $u'(x)$ is whiten he integral in the formula not within the answer to the integral (Right hand side of formula). It's better to do $u$ substitutions as showed in the answer that way you don't have to memorize formulas.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost right:

$$u(x) = x^2 + 1$$

$$du = 2x dx$$

Which when plugged in gives:

$$\int 2xe^{x^2 + 1} dx = \int e^u du = e^u + C = e^{x^2 + 1} + C$$